# Dataset of real addresses?

Tags: address

I am searching for addresses with following components: `postal code`, `contry`, `city`, `street name`, `house number`.

Where I can get such a dataset. I need only 100 row in a csv file.

Comment: openstreetmap.org has many of these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in Kaggle datasets. For example https://www.kaggle.com/openaddresses/openaddresses-europe contains the list of addresses in Europe per country.